# at Kali Linux how to get the library of specific command of package

Tags: ubuntu, security, installation, repository, kali-linux

how can i know the required library for a specific package or a specific command
For example : 
when i write 
apt-get install build-essentials i get a msg ( command not found or unable to locate ) 
so we download the library  libc6-dev g++ by 
sudo apt install libc6-dev g++ 
then re install ( sudo apt install build-essentials ) and it will be installed 
so how we can know that the library libc6-dev g++ is related to build-essentials

Answer (score 0):

Use `apt-cache depends build-essential` to list dependencies.

See [apt-cache manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-cache.8.en.html) if you need more details.